# Convert matrix values to number of cells with a given value

Tags: r, matrix, converters

I have a `data.frame` containing 5 columns, each of which holds a proportion of the whole. Here's what it looks like:

```
Sample    Type_A    Type_B    Type_C    Type_D    Type_E    Sum
00001      54        13         24        3          6      100
00002      5         2          15        54        24      100
00003      10        10         23        37        20      100
```

I want to create a 100-column `matrix` and populate the cells proportionate to their values in my `data.frame`. Row 00001 would look have `A` in the first 50 cells, then 13 cells with `B` in them, then 24 cells with `C` in them, etc.

The desired matrix would look something like this:

```
00001  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A .....
00002  A  A  A  A  A  B  B  C  C  C  C  C  C  C .....
00003  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  B  B  B  B .....
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Your first row doesn't sum up to 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option with `data.table` (Assuming that the values in the "Type" columns sum to 100 for all the rows).

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- sub(".*_", "", grep("_", names(df1), value=TRUE))
setDT(df1)[, transpose(list(rep(nm1, unlist(.SD)))),
    by = Sample ,.SDcols = Type_A:Type_E]
# Sample V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39 V40 V41 V42 V43 V44 V45 V46 V47 V48
#1:  00001  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
#2:  00002  A  A  A  A  A  B  B  C  C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D
#3:  00003  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A   A   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   D   D   D   D   D
#   V49 V50 V51 V52 V53 V54 V55 V56 V57 V58 V59 V60 V61 V62 V63 V64 V65 V66 V67 V68 V69 V70 V71 V72 V73 V74 V75 V76 V77 V78 V79 V80 V81 V82 V83 V84 V85 V86 V87 V88 V89 V90 V91 V92 V93 V94 V95
#1:   A   A   A   A   A   A   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   D   D   D   E
#2:   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E
#3:   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E
#   V96 V97 V98 V99 V100
#1:   E   E   E   E    E
#2:   E   E   E   E    E
#3:   E   E   E   E    E
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that your first sample does not add up to 100 but 96. For the sake of the example I'll use 54.

Try `rep`:

```
rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),c(54,13,24,3,6))

# "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
# "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
# "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D"
# "D" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E" "E"
```

In the case of your data frame, I'd do something like this (but it can probably be done with less code):

```
# Some preparation
df2 <- df[,2:(ncol(df)-1)] # selecting just the types
names(df2) <- gsub("Type_", "", names(df2)) # Removing "Type_" from the variable names

# Apply rep to all rows
lis <- apply(df2,1,function(x) rep(names(df2),x))
t(as.matrix(lis))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a quick hacky solution, if that's okay. First I make some fake data that semi-matches the data you semi-provided.

```
library(plyr)
dat <-  matrix(c(50,14,24,12, 50,50,0,0), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(dat) <- paste('Type_', LETTERS[1:4], sep='')
```

Then I use a really clunky `strsplit` command to get the letters out of the `colnames` and use an `apply` statement to `rep` the letters based on the values in the cell. Note that it will not work if your rows don't sum to 100.

```
adply(data,1,function(x){
     nms <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(colnames(dat), '_'), function(x)x[2]))
     rep(nms, x)})[,-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution.  There may be a cleaner way of handling this

```
### Vectorize "rep"
vec_rep <- function(x,y) {
    unlist(lapply(1:length(x), function(z) { paste(rep(x[z], y[z]), collapse = '') }))
}

df2 <-
    df %>%
    select(-Sum)                                    %>% # Col not needed
    gather(Type, TypeVal, -Sample)                  %>% # Reshape data to long format
    mutate(tstr = vec_rep(gsub('^[^_]+_','', Type), TypeVal)) %>% # create strings of desired lengths
    arrange(Sample, Type)                           %>% # Sort
    group_by(Sample)                                %>% # 
    summarise(NewVal = paste(tstr, collapse=''))        # Create desired string based on grouping
```

`df2` is a data frame that can be converted into a matrix.